# Search and replace an XML field content with SAX

Tags: java, xml, sax

In my Java mapping, I need to search and replace an ASCII control char (BEL - 0x07) which is breaking the mapping routing as the XML can't be parsed.

The current java mapping, although hard coded for the control char (just to be simple and make it work), is working but taking a very long time (30 minutes) due to the source XML size (~5mb).

Would it be quicker using SAX parser?
Can anyone shed some light on this as I'm not very experienced in Java coding?

Here's my source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns:ShipmentStatusList xmlns:ns="http://namespace.com/ShipmentStatus/100">
    <Recordset>
        <ShipmentStatusDetails>
            <CarInitial>CAR</CarInitial>
            <CarNumber>1111</CarNumber>
            <ShipmentDateTime>07-14-201700:00:00:000</ShipmentDateTime>
            <TripRef1/>
            <TripRef2/>
            <TripRef3>7/18/2016</TripRef3>
            <TripComments>[BEL] control char comes here</TripComments>
            <ReturnCity>City</ReturnCity>
            <ReturnState>ST</ReturnState>
        </ShipmentStatusDetails>
    </Recordset>
</ns:ShipmentStatusList>
```

I need the easiest/quickest way to search and replace the [BEL] char by a readable character (like '?').

Here's how I'm doing (which is taking a long time to complete for the heavy source XML's):

```
package com.map;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;

import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.AbstractTransformation;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.StreamTransformationException;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.TransformationInput;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.TransformationOutput;

public class JM_StrippingInvalidXMLChars extends AbstractTransformation {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        /*This method is used only for tests (reading and writing files locally)*/
        try{
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Sync\\in.xml"));

            String inputPayload = JM_StrippingInvalidXMLChars.convertInputStreamToString(input);
            String outputPayload = JM_StrippingInvalidXMLChars.cleanUp(inputPayload);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void transform(TransformationInput arg0, TransformationOutput arg1)
    throws StreamTransformationException {
        getTrace().addInfo("JAVA program StrippingInvalidXMLChars started");
        String inputPayload = convertInputStreamToString(arg0.getInputPayload().getInputStream());
        String outputPayload = cleanUp(inputPayload);
        try {
            arg1.getOutputPayload().getOutputStream().write(
                    outputPayload.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch 
            (Exception exception1) {
        }
}

    public static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream in) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            int ch;
            while ((ch = in.read()) > -1) {
                sb.append((char) ch);
            }
            reader.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception exception) {
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String cleanUp(String instructions){
        String res = "";
        String c = "";
        String strRplc = "?";
        int hexCode = 0;

        if (instructions != null && instructions.length()>0){
            for (int i=0; i<instructions.length(); i++){
                c = instructions.substring(i, i+1);
                hexCode = c.hashCode();
                //if (hexCode>31 && hexCode<127 && hexCode != 96){
                if (hexCode!= 07){
                    res = res.concat(c);
                }else{
                    res = res.concat(strRplc);
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: is that character causing parsing exceptions? or you just want to get rid of this char?

Comment: It's causing parsing exceptions..... and I want to replace it

Comment: have you considered using regex to do a search and replace using shell script and scripting language like perl and python?

Comment: I don't think I'd be able to use such script as I have to write this routine, generate a JAR file and import in another application.
My options seems to be restrict to DOM and SAX. Can you suggest how this code would be?

Comment: if your xml is not well-formed, you may run into problems with DOM or sax...

Comment: There is regex api available in java as well... do a line by line read-in using buffered stream, and then search and replace...